# Only Allow IMDB LINK REGEX solution PHP

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I want a regex solution to allow only 
http://www.imdb.com/title/ttANYNumberWOrdetc/ links

Otherwise SHOW us error.. `Incorrect link`

I am not too good with regex

I just create this petren ..

`preg_match('/http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/(.*)\//is', 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087469/', $result);`

Its show me corect result but i think i missed some thing..

Thanks,

Comment: You should give it a shot first at least. If you want people to write your code you may be in the wrong place.

Comment: @Evert i just add my pettern let me know its okay?

Comment: even i use `asdfasdfhttp://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087469/asdfasdf` its show me correct URL.. i just need to verify the link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this: `http://(?:www\.)?imdb.com/title/tt[^/]+/`.

**Example:**

```
<?php

if ( preg_match('#^http://(?:www\.)?imdb\.com/title/tt[^/]+/$#', 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448303/') )
  echo 'Matches' . PHP_EOL;
```

**Explanation:**

The regular expression matches a string that starts with `http://` followed either by `imdb.com` or `www.imdb.com`, then `/title/tt` followed by any character except for a `/` and that ends with a `/`.

The `#` is the delimiter, the `^` indicated the beginning of the string and the `$` the end.

Comment: its not helping me becuase if i try `asdfasdfhttp://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087469/asdfasdfasdfasfd` its always show's me the correct url.. my code.. `$result=preg_match('#http://(?:www\.)?imdb.com/title/tt[^/]+/#', 'asdfasdfhttp://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087469/asdfasdfasdfasfd', $result);
        if ($result==''){
            echo "Incorect URL";
        }   else {
            echo "correct URL";
        }
`

Comment: I corrected it. I forgot to include the `^` and `#` characters. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think you meant "**and the `$` the end**".

Comment: Instead of http you can use (http||https) to also handle use of the secure form.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if (preg_match("#^(http://www.|https://www.)imdb.com/title/tt([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:/)(?:^[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$#s", 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364845/', $matches)) {
  echo 'yay';
} else {
  echo 'nay';
}
```

Comment: same problem if i use `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364845/asdfasdf` its show me **yay**